# Check if one cell of several cells on a row in Excel has length 30

Tags: excel, cell, string-length, vba

I have several rows within each row several cells and I want to check if one of these cells in a row has length 30.

I tried using the LEN function, but the problem is that I have to check several cells in the row at one moment.

Comment: How do you plan to do it then? You will have to use `Len` in each corresponding `cell (row)` and then probably filter for the Length which is equal to 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel treats TRUE as 1 and FALSE as 0. If you get an array of TRUE/FALSE values from comparing each cell in a row for a length of 30 and take the maximum, you will know if at least one cell has a length of 30.

To check A2:G2 for any cell that has an untrimmed length of 30 characters/digits put this in H2,

```
=AND(MAX(INDEX(--(LEN(A2:G2)=30),,)))
```

Fill down for subsequent rows.

To retrieve the first value that is 30 characters/digits in length put this into I2,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A2:$G2, , SMALL(INDEX(COLUMN($A:$G)+(LEN($A2:$G2)<>30)*1E+99, , ), COLUMN(A:A))), "")
```

Fill right for possible second, third, etc. values that are 30 characters wide. Fill down as necessary to catch subsequent rows.

Comment: Oops - my bad... I see now that you were looking for a VBA solution.

Comment: No, actually a formule like the first one is also good, even better. But if I understand it well, in the place of '--' I have to put the range (say A2:G15), but what do I have to put in the commas? Just leave it that way?

Comment: You asked to 'check if one of these cells **in a row**'; A2:G15 is 14 rows. If you need to examine more than a single row or a single column then these are not appropriate. Please clarify.

Comment: My bad, I rewrited the formula and now it works. Indeed that's what I asked for. In order to have it work for the other rows, I just apply the same formule on them (taking into account the row ranges).

Comment: @Fernando - Well the first boolean formula seems to survive additional rows, but the latter does not and will only work on a single row at one time. Do you require the latter to function in multiple rows? There may be a way to accomplish it.

Comment: No, I have subsequent rows with each several cells, but I perform the test on each row, since I want to know if in any row, there is a cell of length 30.